# joining two or more tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables like I describe below:

TransactionHeader

```
ID    |   ProcessID   |   BillingHeaderID
1             1                  1
2             2                  2
```

TransactionDetail

```
ID    |   ProcessID   |   BillingDetailID
1             1                  1
2             1                  2
```

BillingDetail

```
BillingDetailID |   BillingHeaderID  |   Amount
3                      2                  10000
4                      2                  20000
5                      2                  10000
6                      1                  10000 
7                      1                  10000
```

I'm doing this so far

```
select
    b.ID as ID_TransacHeader,
    a.ID as ID_TransacDetail,
    b.ProcessID
    ,a.BillingDetailID as Before
    ,c.BillingDetailID as After
from TransactionDetail a
inner join TransactionHeader b on a.ProcessID = b.ProcessID
inner join billingdetail c on b.BillingHeaderID = c.BillingHeaderID
```

what I'd like to get as a result something like this:

```
ID_TrnsacHeader   |  ID_TransacDetail  | ProcessID  | Before  |  After
     1                       1               1          1          6
     1                       2               1          2          7
```

The problem is my query above resulting something like this :

```
ID_TrnsacHeader   |  ID_TransacDetail  | ProcessID  | Before  |  After
     1                       1               1          1          6
     1                       2               1          2          6
     1                       1               1          1          7
     1                       2               1          2          7
```

My goal is to show difference between BillingDetailID on table TransactionDetail which is i called by "Before" and BillingDetailID on table BillingDetail which is i called by "After".
Anyone can give me a directions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you choosing which of the four possible rows you want?

Comment: What are the rules that you are attempting to apply to this query?

Comment: @selalu ...Just add one more condition on billing detail (a.billingdetailid = c.billingdetailid)

Comment: That's why i asking Gordon. My query above resulting four rows, meanwhile i expect 2 rows like i describe above. Do you have any idea how to solve that problem Gordon?any help appriciated

Comment: @Kishore...I dont think it's possible. Because my goal is to show difference between BillingDetailID on table TransactionDetail and BillingDetail

Comment: There are two rows in BillingDetail with BillingHeaderID = 1. If you can not tell us which of the two you want to show (you are now getting both!) then there is _no_ way _any_ version of SQL will be able to guess that for you. So you better find a way of telling us (or yourself) how _you_ know when you want the value `6` or `7` back, and when.

Answer (score 1):

try this.......

```
select
    b.ID as ID_TransacHeader,
    a.ID as ID_TransacDetail,
    b.ProcessID
    ,a.BillingDetailID as Before
    ,c.BillingDetailID as After
from TransactionDetail a
inner join TransactionHeader b on a.ProcessID = b.ProcessID
inner join billingdetail c on b.BillingHeaderID = c.BillingHeaderID and a.billingdetailid = c.billingdetailid
```

Comment: I dont think it's possible. Because my goal is to show difference between BillingDetailID on table TransactionDetail and BillingDetail. If i add one more condition like your suggestion it will return 0 rows

Answer (score 0):

To join two or more tables this example might help you:

```
select *
from
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        on a.common = b.common
        inner join 
    TableC c
        on b.common = c.common
```